# Book for Mathematics applied to engineering

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, laplace-transform, book-recommendation, applications

I need a reference (book or lecture notes) for engineering which covers the following subjects:

1. Preliminaries of integration, series of functions, simple and uniform convergences.
2. Laplace Transform and Applications
3. Fourier transform and applications
4. Z-Transform and Applications
5. Distributions
6. Special functions, gamma, beta, Bessel functions

Comment: Something like Boas's *Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences* has everything except the $Z$ transform. That's a more specialized topic you'll find more readily in an engineering book on digital signal processing. Question: when you say "Distributions", do you mean statistical distributions? Or distribution theory, such as for the Dirac Delta distribution?

Comment: @AdrianKeister I mean the Dirac Delta distribution

Comment: In that case, Boas will do very well for everything except the $Z$ transform.

Comment: @AdrianKeister thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

A classic textbook is [Advanced Engineering Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470458364) by Erwin Kreyszig. The textbook itself is 1280 pages long and covers everything in the your list outside of Z-Transforms. I used the textbook for an upper level undergraduate engineering mathematics course and found the explanations to be suitable to an engineer. The textbook also includes a large amount of practice problems. If you are interested in functional analysis, Kreysig also wrote [Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471504599).

If you are interested in learning more about applied mathematics at the research level, I would recommend the [Princeton Companion to Applied Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691150397).

Answer (score 2):

Try any one of the following ...

**Higher Engineering Mathematics** by *B.S. Grewal*.

**Advanced Engineering Mathematics** by *Erwin Kreyszig*

**Advanced Engineering Mathematics** by *R. K. Jain* and *S.R.K. Iyengar*

**Advanced Engineering Mathematics** by *Dennis G Zill* and *Warren S Wright*